# Javascript validation

Tags: javascript

My issue is i need to validate the Card(Master, Visa, etc). In this i have to check different condition for different cards.. and i am using the following way to validate..

```
"CardNumber" : ["CardNumber", /^[51-55]{16}$/, true, "Please enter the valid card number."]
```

here i can check only master card and i need to check many card.. and the card number is the name of the text box of card number which we get from the user and the Card types are shown in a drop down and its name would be Card type,,, so how i need to use the above validation for all all card type....

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, there is a solution for this [already available](http://javascript.internet.com/forms/val-credit-card.html), so you can check it out instead of implementing your own solution, since it's better to use tried and tested implementations.

Comment: I think we can optimize this answer. Any way nice answer.. :)